# Search Bar controller in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary, uisearchresultscontroller

Hello I am trying to implement a SearchBarController but If I type something in the search bar data doesn't comes up according to the letters typed. Here is my code

```
class  CountriesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var dict = NSDictionary() 

  var filterTableData =  NSDictionary()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getCountriesNamesFromServer()

        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller


        })()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

        return self.filterTableData.count-1
        }else {
        return dict.count-1
        }



    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CountriesTableViewCell

         if(self.resultSearchController.active){
           // (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel).text = filterTableData[indexPath.row]

            cell.countryNameLabel.text = (((filterTableData["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Countries"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            return cell

         }else{

         cell.countryNameLabel.text = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Countries"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            return cell
        }


}

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        let keys: NSArray = dict.allKeys
        let filteredKeys: [String] = keys.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)) as! [String]
       filterTableData = dict.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(filteredKeys)

    }
```

I think Problem is in this function `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` because first I think I have to remove the object from Nsdictionary. I know in Array we do this

```
 filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
```

and I think for `NSDictionary` I have to use `NSMUtableDictionary` But I don't know if that is the problem. If it is the problem still don't know how can I remove objects from `NSMutableDictionary` and in short to make this search functionality workable.

Note: Data is Populating successfully in `tableView`.. just the search functionality is not working

Comment: Have your tried tableview.reloadData() in the end of your updateSearchResultsForSearchController method?

THis will tell the table to reload and should use the new array. Also make sure the isActive method returns as expected

Comment: yes I did. but still it isn't working @JohnMejia

Comment: Does filterTableData have records? Are you stepping through, is it going into your if(self.resultSearchController.active) condition??

Comment: yes it is going but filterTableData has no records. its empty